# Python api for OpenCV library

Tags: python, opencv

I use Python api for OpenCV Library and it's great. I want to adapt the same technology to my own C++ library. Here is the source code:

https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/modules/python/src2

As far as I know this is not SWIG, or Cython but a manual approach. Can someone please explain the architecture of the Python wrapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the python scripts in opencv\modules\python\src2 are used to generate the api

first hdr_parser.py is run on the opencv c++header files (just try to run it!), to collect the classes/functions(that's what the EXPORTS_W and CV_WRAP tags are for in the c++ headers),

then gen2.py is the 'backend', which generates the python wrappers.

the java / matlab bindings are done in the very same way (just different backends)